# Conditional Statement giving seemingly wrong answer: What am I missing

Tags: perl

So I have to make a simple calculator in Perl that maintains an accumulator and does simple operations. The accumulator starts at 0 and then changes based on the results that I receive. At the moment I am only trying to get addition to work. When I check to ensure that the operator entered is + something goes wrong. For instance:

Accumulator: 0
Operator: Anything put here results in addition. Including this sentence.
Operand: 4

Accumulator: 4

It catches numbers but nothing else. I have tried using grep and a list of the operators. I have exhausted all of my ideas. Here is my code (Fyi first post so help me with any noob errors):

```
my $running = 1;
my $accum = "0";
my $operator;
my $operand;

print("Welcome to the simple, command line calculator.\n");
print("To terminate, press Control-C.\n\n");

while ($running){

    print("\nAccumulator: ".$accum."\n");
    print("Operator: ");
    $operator = <STDIN>;
    if ($operator == "+"){
            print("Operand: ");
            operand = <STDIN>;
            $accum += $operand;
    }
    else{
        print("Invalid operator: ".$operator."\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot `use warnings FATAL => "all";`.

Comment: Hey, did you notice that in line 16 you omitted the "$" sigil from the variable $operand? That can't help.

Answer (score 13):

Perl doesn't remove the ending newline from input unless you use the `-l` option, so you're comparing `"+"` against `"+\n"`.  Usually you want to do soemthing like `chomp($operator);`.

That said, your *real* problem is that `==` does numeric comparison, and both `"+"` and `"+\n"` evaluate to 0 in numeric context.  (Using `-w`, as you should *always* do, would warn you about this.)  Use the `eq` operator for string comparison.

Comment: Don't use `-w`, use the `warnings` pragma is better. See the perldoc for perllexwarn for discussion - http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html

Comment: @daotoad: That depends on the perl version; in the versions of 5.8 I've had to use in some places, `-w` catches some things `use warnings` doesn't.  (This was clearly a bug in those versions, as it works as expected in 5.10+.)

Comment: Perl 5.6 added lexical warnings, and there were a bunch of issues with Perl 5.6.0.  I haven't ever had any problems with lexical warnings under the 5.8.x series.  As people still seem to use these old versions, I'd love to see examples of warnings that get missed.

Comment: @daotoad: I'd have to reinstall 5.8 to get them again. I have (through both some luck and some deliberate wrangling) never had to deal with any 5.6 release; I was seeing these on MacPorts' 5.8.9. (I should mention that the flip side of that was being stuck with 5.00503 for far too long....)

Comment: `-l` adds a chomp to the implicit loop of `-n` or `-p` (and has other effects); `-0` does not.

Answer (score 3):

`==` compares numbers, not strings. If you compare strings, the strings will be converted to numbers; for non-numeric strings, this means they become `0`. So `$operator == "+"` becomes `0 == 0`.

For strings, use `eq` instead. Additionally, keep in mind that `<STDIN>` will preserve newlines; make sure to `chomp $operator` as well.

Comment: I tried that but it still did not work. It just tells me that everything is an invalid operator including +

Comment: `perl -e 'print("a random string" == 0, "\n")'`.  Strings that don't start with a number become 0 when converted to numbers, even though they're truthy in other contexts.

Comment: @Better: See [geekosaur's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560551/conditional-statement-giving-seemingly-wrong-answer-what-am-i-missing/5560562#5560562).  The numeric vs string issue was only half the problem.